# Почему возвращает ошибку DAR101 Missing parameter(s) in Docstring?

Tags: python, doc, linter

Python 3.8.5, poetry, линтер wemake-python-styleguide

```
def test_app_airflights(test_client):
    """Check the availability of the web application.

    Args:
        test_client (fixture - class flask.testing.FlaskClient): application
            Flask for functionaly testing.
    """
    assert test_client.get('/main_page').status_code == 200
```

проверка линтером возвращает ошибку `DAR101 Missing parameter(s) in Docstring: - test_client`

Почему? параметр же есть в документации функции. Документацию проверяет [Darglint](https://github.com/terrencepreilly/darglint#error-codes)

Answer (score 0):

сам разобрался

`test_client (fixture class flask.testing.FlaskClient): application`

нужно убрать `-`  после `fixture`